# How to match, but not consume, a path prefix in Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

my Akka HTTP application reverse-proxies some requests to an internal HTTP system:

```
pathPrefix("/api/") {
  (path("some-upload-endpoint") & post) {
    withSizeLimit(10 * 1024 * 1024) {
      reverseProxyToBackend(rc)
    }
  } ~ reverseProxyToBackend(rc)
}
```

`reverseProxyToBackend` is a custom directive that takes the incoming requests, adds some headers and forwards it to the backend system, based on the remaining *unmatched* path.  IOW, `/api/foobar` becomes `backend.example.com/foobar`.

For a certain path `some-upload-endpoint` however I need to increase the default size limit of the frontend, as we expect larger requests to this endpoint.

Unfortunately, `path("some-upload-endpoint")` *consumes* the remaining path, so with the above code `reverseProxyToBackend` would forward to `backend.example.com` rather than `backend.example.com/some-upload-endpoint`, which is not what I want.

How can I match a path in Akka HTTP, but *not* consume it?  In other words, what directives can I use to keep the unmatched path untouched by a path matcher?  And if there's no such directive, how can I restore the unmatched path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`extractMatchedPath`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/basic-directives/extractMatchedPath.html#extractmatchedpath) should "reconstitute" the path that was already matched.  From the documentation:

> The extractMatchedPath directive extracts the path that was already
>   matched by any of the PathDirectives (or any custom ones that change
>   the unmatched path field of the request context). You can use it for
>   building directives that use already matched part in their logic.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ramon's answer, you can restore the unmatched path using mapRequestContext:

```
extractMatchedPath { matchedPath =>
  mapRequestContext(_.withUnmatchedPath(matchedPath)) { // reset the "unmatchedPath"
    ...
  }
}
```

You might also be interested in pathPrefixTest, rawPathPrefixTest, etc.  Basically pathPrefixTest is like pathPrefix but it does not "consume" the path segments.